# How do i use DbContext to call stored procedure and map the result set to the model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I am using DbContext to call the stored procedure in my MVC application.
Below is the code i used to call the stored procedure and map with my model properties.

```
List<myModel> _listMyModel = new List<myModel>();
using (var ctx = new DbContext("ConnectionString1"))
{
    var param = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@Param",
        Value = strLob,
        SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar
    };

    ctx.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
    _listMyModel = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<myModel>("exec MyProc @Param", param).ToList();
```

But the issue here is, if the stored procedure result set have some space or data type is different then it throws exception.

I just need here instead using this is there any other way to map result set with the model properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one scenario for the above asked.
Get the result set using normal sql command and fill in datatable.
After that use entitytomodel approach to have the specific column customized and set in generic list properties.

e.g: like below:

```html
 var dataTable = _dbLibrary.GetDataTable(1, "Proc_Name", Parameters);
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                _listGenric = (from DataRow row in dataTable.Rows
                select new GenericList
                {
                     ListItem1 = row["Column Name"].ToString(),

                }).ToList();
            }
```

And this approach is working for me.